# Query execution in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have a situation where I need to fetch details of an employee from the database using his ID and display them in the browser.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM employeesalarypayment WHERE empid = ".$val['empid'].";";`

`$query = $this->db->query($sql);`

These are the statements that I have written to get the result array. My problem is how do I take a single field/column from this array? Also have I done it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $row = $query->result_array();  will this work? @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: $row = $query->row_array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query return single data from database then you need to use

```
$row = $query->row_array()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employeesalarypayment WHERE empid = ".$val['empid'].";";

$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();


echo  $result[0]['field_name'];
```

Comment: I used Mayank 's answer, it works, but thank you for your help & input. @BIBIN JOHN